# Quaternion from Orthogonal Basis

Tags: game-physics, quaternions

I have a projectile object that is moving along a velocity vector.  I need to ensure that the object is always facing in the direction of the velocity vector.  Furthermore, I am representing object rotation using quaternions, not matrices.

I know that the first step is to find an orthogonal basis:

```
forward = direction of velocity vector
up = vector.new(0, 1, 0)
right = cross(up, forward) 
up = cross(forward, right)
```

How might I convert the basis into a rotation quaternion?

**Solution**

Note, I'd like to give credit to Noel Hughes for providing the answer, but I want to clarify with my own experiences.  Pseudocode follows:

```
   vec3 vel = direction of velocity vector
   vec3 forward = (1, 0, 0)  // Depends on direction your model faces. See below.
   vec3 axis = cross(forward, vel)
   if (axis == 0) then quit // Already facing the right direction!
   axis = normalize(axis)
   float theta = acos(vel.x/sqrt(vel.x^2, vel.y^2, vel.z^2))
   quat result = (0, axis.y * sin(theta/2), axis.z * sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2)
```

The last element of the quaternion is the scalar part, the first three elements are the imaginary parts.  Also, the above pseudocode assumes that your object in "model space" points down the positive x-axis.  In my case, the object actually pointed down the positive y-axis, in which case I made the following changes:

```
   vec3 vel = direction of velocity vector
   vec3 forward = (0, 1, 0)  // Note that y-component is now 1
   vec3 axis = cross(forward, vel)
   if (axis == 0) then quit 
   axis = normalize(axis)
   float theta = acos(vel.x/sqrt(vel.x^2, vel.y^2, vel.z^2))
   quat result = (axis.x * sin(theta/2), 0, axis.z * sin(theta/2), cos(theta/2)
   // Note that SECOND component above is now 0
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551983/405017), which considers the world Up axis to keep the quaternion from rolling.

Comment: Please do not update your question to include the solution; post an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you don't care about the orientation of your projectile, other than having the longitudinal axis aligned with the velocity vector, and that the longitudinal axis is the x axis of (1, 0, 0).

You are on the right track.  Normalize the velocity vector, (vx, vy, vz)/sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2) cross the x axis with it and normalize the result - (0, yn, zn) - this is the rotation axis for the quaternion.  The rotation angle is simply theta =  inverse cosine of vx/sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2).  The resultant quaternion is then

(0, yn, zn)sn(theta/2) cos(theta/2)

Comment: So, I can build the quaternion using (0, yn, zn) as the rotation axis and theta as the rotation angle?  I have a method for creating a quaternion this way:

    qx = ax * sin(angle/2)
    qy = ay * sin(angle/2)
    qz = az * sin(angle/2)
    qw = cos(angle/2)

Comment: I wish this answer didn't ignore the "orientation" (roll) of the projectile, and ignore the `up` axis. This answer is fine for a projectile, but no good for a camera!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that better matches the title:
"Quaternion from Orthogonal Basis"

The question and answers as stated above address the problem of aligning a quaternion along a vector ('pointing') but ignore twist (orientation). A complete orthonormal basis includes direction, up and side (one of those being redundant but not two). The original question only considers direction.

One solution for quaternions-from-orthogonal-basis can be found by placing the 3x vectors into the columns of a matrix, then converting the matrix to a quaternion. However, this method requires additional matrix storage (16x floats) in addition to the quaternion, and is quite slow.

A better solution is found by writing out the basis vectors a,b,c and plugging these into the matrix-to-quaternion conversion, where the elements are explicit. (This matrix is in column-major, OpenGL form)

```
m[0][0] = a.x, m[1][0] = a.y, m[2][0] = a.z
m[0][1] = b.x, m[1][1] = b.y, m[2][1] = b.z
m[0][2] = c.x, m[1][2] = c.z, m[2][2] = c.z
```

Now, we rewrite the matrix-to-quaternion function using the substituted orthonormal vectors a,b,c. The result is the following function:

```
// Quaternion from orthogonal basis
Quaternion& Quaternion::toBasis (Vector3DF a, Vector3DF b, Vector3DF c)
{
    float T = a.x + b.y + c.z;
    float s;
    if (T > 0) {
        float s = sqrt(T + 1) * 2.f;
        X = (b.z - c.y) / s;
        Y = (c.x - a.z) / s;
        Z = (a.y - b.x) / s;
        W = 0.25f * s;
    } else if ( a.x > b.y && a.x > c.z) {
        s = sqrt(1 + a.x - b.y - c.z) * 2;
        X = 0.25f * s;
        Y = (a.y + b.x) / s;
        Z = (c.x + a.z) / s;
        W = (b.z - c.y) / s;
    } else if (b.y > c.z) {
        s = sqrt(1 + b.y - a.x - c.z) * 2;
        X = (a.y + b.x) / s;
        Y = 0.25f * s;
        Z = (b.z + c.y) / s;
        W = (c.x - a.z) / s;
    } else {
        s = sqrt(1 + c.z - a.x - b.y) * 2;
        X = (c.x + a.z) / s;
        Y = (b.z + c.y) / s;
        Z = 0.25f * s;
        W = (a.y - b.x) / s;
    }
    normalize();
    return *this;
}
```

This function gives a quaternion (X,Y,Z,W) directly from the orthonormal basis vectors a,b,c without intermediate storage of a matrix. (Matrices above in column-major, OpenGL form). You may still need to normalize the quaternion. If you have a direction and up-vector, say for a camera, you can construct the basis as: a=dir, b=up, c=cross(dir,up)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity (or a similar library that provides this functionality), the function you want is [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html).

Just pass in the forward and up vectors you want to use, and it will return the corresponding Quaternion.