# Look-at quaternion using up vector

Tags: quaternions

I have a camera (in a custom 3D engine) that accepts a quaternion for the rotation transform. I have two 3D points representing a camera and an object to look at. I want to calculate the quaternion that looks from the camera to the object, ***while respecting the world up axis***.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12435671) asks for the same thing without the "up" vector. All three answers result in the camera pointing in the correct direction, but rolling (as in yaw/pitch/roll; imagine leaning your head onto your ear while looking at something).

I can calculate an orthonormal basis of vectors that match the desired coordinate system by:

```
lookAt = normalize(target - camera)
sideaxis = cross(lookAt, worldUp)
rotatedup = cross(sideaxis, lookAt)
```

How can I create a quaternion from those three vectors? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620130/quaternion-from-orthogonal-basis) asks for the same thing...but unfortunately the only and accepted answer says ~"let's assume you don't care about roll", and then goes about ignoring the up axis. I do care about roll. I don't want to ignore the up axis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A previous answer has given a valid solution using angles. This answer will present an alternative method.

The orthonormal basis vectors, renaming them `F = lookAt, R = sideaxis, U = rotatedup`, directly form the *columns* of the 3x3 rotation matrix which is equivalent to your desired quaternion:

[image]

Multiplication with a vector is equivalent to using said vector's components as the coordinates in the camera's basis.

A 3x3 rotation matrix can be converted into a quaternion *without* conversion to angles / use of costly trigonometric functions. Below is a numerically stable C++ snippet which does this, returning a normalized quaternion:

```
inline void CalculateRotation( Quaternion& q ) const {
  float trace = a[0][0] + a[1][1] + a[2][2];
  if( trace > 0 ) {
    float s = 0.5f / sqrtf(trace + 1.0f);
    q.w = 0.25f / s;
    q.x = ( a[2][1] - a[1][2] ) * s;
    q.y = ( a[0][2] - a[2][0] ) * s;
    q.z = ( a[1][0] - a[0][1] ) * s;
  } else {
    if ( a[0][0] > a[1][1] && a[0][0] > a[2][2] ) {
      float s = 2.0f * sqrtf( 1.0f + a[0][0] - a[1][1] - a[2][2]);
      q.w = (a[2][1] - a[1][2] ) / s;
      q.x = 0.25f * s;
      q.y = (a[0][1] + a[1][0] ) / s;
      q.z = (a[0][2] + a[2][0] ) / s;
    } else if (a[1][1] > a[2][2]) {
      float s = 2.0f * sqrtf( 1.0f + a[1][1] - a[0][0] - a[2][2]);
      q.w = (a[0][2] - a[2][0] ) / s;
      q.x = (a[0][1] + a[1][0] ) / s;
      q.y = 0.25f * s;
      q.z = (a[1][2] + a[2][1] ) / s;
    } else {
      float s = 2.0f * sqrtf( 1.0f + a[2][2] - a[0][0] - a[1][1] );
      q.w = (a[1][0] - a[0][1] ) / s;
      q.x = (a[0][2] + a[2][0] ) / s;
      q.y = (a[1][2] + a[2][1] ) / s;
      q.z = 0.25f * s;
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion

Converting this to suit your situation is of course just a matter of swapping the matrix elements with the corresponding vector components:

```
// your code from before
F = normalize(target - camera);   // lookAt
R = normalize(cross(F, worldUp)); // sideaxis
U = cross(R, F);                  // rotatedup

// note that R needed to be re-normalized
// since F and worldUp are not necessary perpendicular
// so must remove the sin(angle) factor of the cross-product
// same not true for U because dot(R, F) = 0

// adapted source
Quaternion q;
double trace = R.x + U.y + F.z;
if (trace > 0.0) {
  double s = 0.5 / sqrt(trace + 1.0);
  q.w = 0.25 / s;
  q.x = (U.z - F.y) * s;
  q.y = (F.x - R.z) * s;
  q.z = (R.y - U.x) * s;
} else {
  if (R.x > U.y && R.x > F.z) {
    double s = 2.0 * sqrt(1.0 + R.x - U.y - F.z);
    q.w = (U.z - F.y) / s;
    q.x = 0.25 * s;
    q.y = (U.x + R.y) / s;
    q.z = (F.x + R.z) / s;
  } else if (U.y > F.z) {
    double s = 2.0 * sqrt(1.0 + U.y - R.x - F.z);
    q.w = (F.x - R.z) / s;
    q.x = (U.x + R.y) / s;
    q.y = 0.25 * s;
    q.z = (F.y + U.z) / s;
  } else {
    double s = 2.0 * sqrt(1.0 + F.z - R.x - U.y);
    q.w = (R.y - U.x) / s;
    q.x = (F.x + R.z) / s;
    q.y = (F.y + U.z) / s;
    q.z = 0.25 * s;
  }
}
```

(And needless to say swap `y` and `z` if you're using OpenGL.)

Comment: This looks like the perfect answer—inputs matching mine, points out a bug in my assumption (needing to normalize sideaxis), has sample code, uses MathML—but it doesn't work for me. I am using OpenGL, I have tried with y and z swapped on the inputs. The resulting quaternion never results in pointing at the center of the cube (whether rolled or not). Any guesses as to what's wrong, or how to debug this further?

Comment: @Phrogz hmm I'm not too sure; can you upload the relevant parts of your code, e.g. camera setup? It could be a separate bit of logic causing the problem.

Comment: That last comment was a hair inaccurate. If target is <0,0,0> and camera is <0,0,20> (looking forward down the -Z axis) then everything works out OK :) Would you be willing to meet me in chat to work it out (and if/when we work it out I'll update with relevant code here)?

Comment: @Phrogz no problem (give me 30 minutes though, I'm not at my PC at the moment, thanks)

Comment: The above code works with OpenGL if the F, R, and U vectors are defined as `F=normalize(camera-target)`; `R = normalize(cross(worldup,F))`; `U = cross(F,R)`. My great thanks for @meowgoesthedog's epic help fighting coordinate conversions and helping to debug this.

Comment: Superb answer, a lifesaver for me. @Phrogz comment about reversing the Cross are correct. The reference to OpenGL seems to suggest that the solution is left-handed, whereas it works correctly when things in front of the camera have positive Z

Comment: One of the more useful answers I found on stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if we want to look in the world up direction? i.e. `F == worldUp`

Comment: @csisy that's a singularity in spherical polar coordinates, so you would have to redefine the camera's "up" direction in terms of `worldFront` and `worldSide`

Answer (score 2):

Assume you initially have three ortonormal vectors: worldUp, worldFront and worldSide, and lets use your equations for lookAt, sideAxis and rotatedUp. The worldSide vector will not be necessary to achieve the result.

Break the operation in two. First, rotate around worldUp. Then rotate around sideAxis, which will now actually be parallel to the rotated worldSide.

> Axis1 = worldUp
> Angle1 = (see below)
>
> Axis2 = cross(lookAt, worldUp) = sideAxis
> Angle2 = (see below)

Each of these rotations correspond to a quaternion using:

> Q = cos(Angle/2) + i * Axis_x * sin(Angle/2) + j * Axis_y * sin(Angle/2)  + k * Axis_z * sin(Angle/2)

Multiply both Q1 and Q2 and you get the desired quaternion.

Details for the angles:

Let P(worldUp) be the projection matrix on the worldUp direction, i.e., P(worldUp).v = cos(worldUp,v).worldUp or using kets and bras, P(worldUp) = |worldUp >< worldUp|. Let I be the identity matrix.

1. Project lookAt in the plane perpendicular to worldUp and normalize it.

   > tmp1 = (I - P(worldUp)).lookAt
   > n1 = normalize(tmp1)
2. Angle1 = arccos(dot(worldFront,n1))
3. Angle2 = arccos(dot(lookAt,n1))

EDIT1:

Notice that there is no need to compute transcendental functions. Since the dot product of a pair of normalized vectors is the cosine of an angle and assuming that `cos(t) = x`, we have the trigonometric identities:

- `cos(t/2) = sqrt((1 + x)/2)`
- `sin(t/2) = sqrt((1 - x)/2)`

Answer (score 0):

If somebody search for C# version with handling every matrix edge cases (not input edge cases!), here it is:

```
public static SoftQuaternion LookRotation(SoftVector3 forward, SoftVector3 up)
{
    forward = SoftVector3.Normalize(forward);
    
    // First matrix column
    SoftVector3 sideAxis = SoftVector3.Normalize(SoftVector3.Cross(up, forward));
    // Second matrix column
    SoftVector3 rotatedUp = SoftVector3.Cross(forward, sideAxis);
    // Third matrix column
    SoftVector3 lookAt = forward;

    // Sums of matrix main diagonal elements
    SoftFloat trace1 = SoftFloat.One + sideAxis.X - rotatedUp.Y - lookAt.Z;
    SoftFloat trace2 = SoftFloat.One - sideAxis.X + rotatedUp.Y - lookAt.Z;
    SoftFloat trace3 = SoftFloat.One - sideAxis.X - rotatedUp.Y + lookAt.Z;

    // If orthonormal vectors forms identity matrix, then return identity rotation
    if (trace1 + trace2 + trace3 < SoftMath.CalculationsEpsilon)
    {
        return Identity;
    }

    // Choose largest diagonal
    if (trace1 + SoftMath.CalculationsEpsilon > trace2 && trace1 + SoftMath.CalculationsEpsilon > trace3)
    { 
        SoftFloat s = SoftMath.Sqrt(trace1) * (SoftFloat)2.0f;
        return new SoftQuaternion(
            (SoftFloat)0.25f * s,
            (rotatedUp.X + sideAxis.Y) / s,
            (lookAt.X + sideAxis.Z) / s,
            (rotatedUp.Z - lookAt.Y) / s);
    }
    else if (trace2 + SoftMath.CalculationsEpsilon > trace1 && trace2 + SoftMath.CalculationsEpsilon > trace3)
    { 
        SoftFloat s = SoftMath.Sqrt(trace2) * (SoftFloat)2.0f;
        return new SoftQuaternion(
            (rotatedUp.X + sideAxis.Y) / s,
            (SoftFloat)0.25f * s,
            (lookAt.Y + rotatedUp.Z) / s,
            (lookAt.X - sideAxis.Z) / s);
    }
    else
    { 
        SoftFloat s = SoftMath.Sqrt(trace3) * (SoftFloat)2.0f;
        return new SoftQuaternion(
            (lookAt.X + sideAxis.Z) / s,
            (lookAt.Y + rotatedUp.Z) / s,
            (SoftFloat)0.25f * s,
            (sideAxis.Y - rotatedUp.X) / s);
    }
}
```

This realization based on deeper understanding of [this](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/ethan.htm) conversation, and was tested for many edge case scenarios.

P.S.

- Quaternion's constructor is (x, y, z, w)
- `SoftFloat` is software float type, so you can easyly change it to built-in `float` if needed
- For full edge case safe realization (including input) check [this](https://github.com/nilpunch/soft-math/blob/1d8c10167b0c6fad0d2a4973a36ef199d7ca4123/Runtime/SoftStructs/SoftUnitQuaternion.cs) repo.

Answer (score -3):

lookAt
sideaxis
rotatedup

If you normalize this 3 vectors, it is a components of rotation matrix 3x3. So just convert this rotation matrix to quaternion.

Comment: I suggest that this is a good comment, but without code, not a very useful answer. Can you please show how to do this, in code?

Comment: If you use some math library, it already should have conversion procedure from matrix to quaternion.  If not , use wikipedia for conversion code.